# Регулярное выражение проверка на целое слово не из контекста

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пж, как можно записать регулярное выражение таким образом чтобы
текст вида `Book EliteDisplay` находил Book .

Перед Book и после него может быть сколько угодно пробелов.
т.е хочу проверить есть ли слово целиком, например `sBook   EliteDisplay` не подходит если поймает Book из контекста.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jboJNr/1

Comment: так и знал что проще можно) у меня баланда длинная получилась, спасибо